# Can't make sense of date conversion to UTC

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I have a string containing a date and time in UTC (not part of the string, but I know that it's UTC). So I create an aware datetime object using the following code:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> mystr = '01/09/2018 00:15:00'
>>> start_time = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.strptime(mystr, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
>>> start_time
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 1, 0, 15, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> str(start_time)
'2018-09-01 00:15:00+00:00'
>>> start_time.strftime('%s')
'1535757300'
```

All seems fine now but if I do in the shell:

```
$ TZ=UTC date -d @1535757300
Fri Aug 31 23:15:00 UTC 2018
```

Shouldn't I be getting `Sat Sep  1 00:15:00 UTC 2018` instead (ie, the same date I started with)?

Comment: if you do the reverse (`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1535757300)`) you get the same result as the date utility

Comment: when I run your code, I get `'1535760900'` as my output from `start_time.strftime('%s')`

Comment: @wpercy indeed, I tried it on another machine and I get 1535760900. Any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: It looks like %s is not among the format specifiers listed in https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior, which leaves me a bit surprised.

Comment: You could simplify this a bit with `datetime.strptime('{}+0000'.format(mystr), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S%z')` to avoid the localization step. Then test the result with `datetime.isoformat()` to avoid manual conversion issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the following:

```
int((start_time - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())
```

Because you are using strftime, it's referencing your systems time which is probably in your local timezone. It's more reliable to just calculate it yourself as above.

**EDIT:**

As the follow-up post by OP states, it's easier to just use start_time.timestamp() but that works only in Python 3.3* and up.

Answer (score 0):

After some more tries, it looks like `%s` is not supported among the format specifiers listed in the official documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior. Instead, I get the correct result by using the `timestamp()` method:

```
>>> start_time.timestamp()
1535760900.0
```